# Prevent whenenver gem from running --clear-crontab before gems installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, whenever

I am using capistrano, and the whenever gem, on a fresh deploy to a server without the whenever gem installed, capistrano attempts to run

whenever --clear-crontab

BEFORE the rake gems:install command has been run, its clear (from [this](https://github.com/javan/whenever/blob/master/lib/whenever/capistrano.rb)) that this command runs after deploy_code but so does my command that installs the gems (below)..

```
after "deploy:update_code", "deploy:symlink_config"

deploy.task :symlink_config, :roles => :app do
  # create a symlink to the database.yml file located in the shared_path
  run "ln -nsf #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{current_release}/config"

  # install any missing gems
  run "cd #{current_release} && sudo rake gems:install --trace RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}"

  # migrate the database
  run "cd #{current_release} && rake db:migrate --trace RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}"
end
```

Is there a way to order these tasks, because on a cold deploy I always get **whenever: not found** and have to manually install the whenever gem on the remote server

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is removing the `require "whenever/capistrano"` from the config\deploy.rb to avoid the "automatic" deploy. Instead I have added a task that executes the `--clear-crontab` and `--update-crontab`. This works as it will execute in the sequence I set it to.

I have based it off [this post](http://blog.lucashungaro.com/2012/04/10/capistrano-and-whenever-updating-the-crontab-of-the-runner-user/), which deals with a slightly different problem but has the same solution - not to use the "automatic" integration with capistrano.